# Memory error loading a 1GB .accdb using pypyodbc and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pypyodbc

I'm trying to do something that maybe is not possible or maybe should be done in a different way...

I have to read a 1 GB Access file and manipulate it in pandas; since `cursor.fetchall()` failed directly with `Memory Error`, I tried the function below in order to see when the memory error happens: it appears after 400.000 rows fetched (the total is 1.12 Mrows).

It is strange since I have 8 GB ram in my machine and it seems to be free at 50%. I also set my virtual memory to 16 GB but the result didn't change.

I don't need calculus speed, so any dirty solution is welcome :) including using hard-disk as ram (I have an ssd).

There is maybe a way to make all memory available for python?

**Ways that have already failed:**

- single row fetch: `cursor.fetchone()`
- many rows fetch: `cursor.fetchmany()`
- all rows fetch: `cursor.fetchall()`
- pandas `read_sql` passing `chunksize`: `pandas.read_sql(query, conn, chunksize=chunksize)` (thx to user MaxU)

**Function :**

```
def msaccess_to_df (abs_path, query):
    conn = pypyodbc.connect(
        r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
        r"Dbq=" + abs_path + ";" )

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute( query )

    fields = zip(*cur.description)[0]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=fields)

    fetch_lines_per_block = 5000
    i = 0
    while True:
        rows = cur.fetchmany(fetch_lines_per_block) # <-----
        if len(rows) == 0: break
        else:
            rd = [dict(zip(fields, r)) for r in rows]
            df = df.append(rd, ignore_index=True)
            del rows
            del rd
        i+=1
        print 'fetched', i*fetch_lines_per_block, 'lines'

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return df
```

**THE ERROR :**

```
df = df.append(rd, ignore_index=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4338, in append
    verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 845, in concat
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 904, in __init__
    obj.consolidate(inplace=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2747, in consolidate
    self._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2729, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2718, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2727, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3273, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3278, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4269, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4292, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError
```

**#################### EDIT - SOLVED ####################**

Finally I solved with

- Setting machine virtual memory to 16GB
- Installing Python 64 bit
- Replacing Access drivers with the 64 bit one
  (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255)

With this any method works.

Comment: Ah! Just about to recommend Python 64-bit if your machine allows it. Please post your edit as answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

I would use native pandas method - [read_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) instead of fetching rows manually in loops:

```
def msaccess_to_df (abs_path, query):
    conn = pypyodbc.connect(
        r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
        r"Dbq=" + abs_path + ";" )

    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    conn.close()
    return df
```

if you are still receiving `MemoryError` exception, try to read your data in chunks:

```
def msaccess_to_df (abs_path, query, chunksize=10**5):
    conn = pypyodbc.connect(
        r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
        r"Dbq=" + abs_path + ";" )

    df = pd.concat([x for x in pd.read_sql(query, conn, chunksize=chunksize)],
                   ignore_index=True)
    conn.close()
    return df
```

PS this should give you an idea, but please be aware that i didn't test this code, so it might need some debugging...

Comment: thank you, but also with `chunksize` I still get memory error after a while even if I have 3 GB ram free (viewed in windows resource monitor).